# Automating Disk Cleanup on Windows using commandline

Tags: windows, command-line, automation, syntax, disk-cleanup

I am trying to run Disk Cleanup in the Command Prompt (and through a C# program) and so I went through all the available options from this link:

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315246

Whilst I am just trying to understand what I can do, it would be good if someone could explain why the drive option `/d` cannot be set while specifying `/sagerun:n`.

Or is it possible, by some way, to run `/sagerun` for a specific drive?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `/d` with `/sageset:n`; `/sagerun:n` just runs the configuration as set in the registry key.

In other words, you can't create a set of cleanup options and then run them on individual drives, you have to set cleanup options for each drive.  If you run `/sageset:n` without the `/d` switch then it is supposed to run on all drives when you use `/sagerun:n`.